# How to convert Django datetime to HighCharts format

Tags: django, python-3.x, highcharts

I am trying to display datetime on a chart but having some trouble as it seems to be putting out an odd format to the chart.

**Django template:**

```
var employeeLastLoginWithPoints = [
        {% for employee in employee_list %}
        [{{ employee.last_login|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}, {{ employee.points }}]
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
];
```

**Highcharts snippet:**

```
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
       day: '%b/%d/%Y'
    },
```

**What the chart looks like:**

All the date data is pushed to the left at `Jan/01/1970`

**`Sources/Index` of the DOM:**

```
var employeeLastLoginWithPoints = [
        [01/11/2020, 0]
        , 
        [01/07/2020, 3]
        , 
        [01/11/2020, 14]
        , 
        [01/08/2020, 8]
];
```

**console.log(employeeLastLoginWithPoints)**:

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [0.000045004500450045, 0]
1: (2) [0.00007072135785007072, 3]
2: (2) [0.000045004500450045, 14]
3: (2) [0.00006188118811881188, 8]
```

Why is the console log showing up different and how do I get it to display correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the rendered date in quotes,

```
["{{ employee.last_login|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}", {{ employee.points }}]
```

At the moment you are rendering `01/11/2020` as one of the values, this is being interpreted as the calculation `01 / 11 / 2020` which returns a float